# can we type destination Table name in bulk insert task of ssis

Tags: ssis

I want to use bulk insert task in SSIS but the problem is that in the connection tab destination table is not allowing me to type in the tablename that does not exists. I will create a table using t-sql task.

My SSIS task will be like

Execute sql task -- > Bulk insert task

Execute SQL Task creates a table dbo.mytable and now Bulk insert task should use this newly created table but it does not allow me to give the option to type the newly created table (dbo.mytable) as destination table .

Comment: Have you tried setting "delay validation" to true at the package level?

Comment: I have set it to true but still I am not able to type the table name that does not exists

Comment: I think you need to create the table initially. In the control flow you can DROP it prior to creating it (but why not use TRUNCATE?). This will allow you to set up the necessary Data Flow.

Comment: Yes we need to have table created first and then reference that table. Another limitation i just observed that Bulk insert task does not work for excel files as source

Comment: You could covert the .xls to .csv and then treat the .csv file as a text input. See [https://ashishmit99.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/script-task-for-converting-excel-to-csv/]

Comment: Excel files are treated like small databases because they can have multiple sheets and other more complex structures that CSV doesn't provide. You need to setup a data flow tasks to pull from excel. If you don't want to use a data flow, you will need to convert the data to CSV or another simple text format to use bulk insert.

Comment: You might use "Execute Process Task" pointed to bcp.exe, then you can even create your bcp parameters inside your SSIS package.